# Questions with the homomorphic-encryption tag are better suited for Crypto.SE

Tags: discussion

The questions with the homomorphic-encryption tag are often only tangentially related to the topics in the help center.

The help center says that "using cryptography" is on topic, but the homomorphic encryption questions are more likely to be questions about the properties of a  homomorphic encryption instead of using it. These questions are better suited for Crypto.SE.

Homomorphic-encryption will be more suited here once it begins to get implemented in information systems. Until then, can we suspend or remove the tag?

Alternatively, can we change the tag info of the homomorphic-encryption tag to make the user to consider whether Crypto.SE is a better fit?

Comment: A tag without questions about it would be deleted automatically. So, for a tag to stay there needs to be on-topic questions to be applied to.

Answer (score 7):

I don't think the tag needs to be removed - some questions might be on topic. But adding some helpful advice to the tag info is a great idea. I took the liberty of [doing that](https://security.stackexchange.com/tags/homomorphic-encryption/info). Anyone should feel free to edit if they think they can improve it.

Answer (score 5):

The tag itself can stay, as it might be relevant for someone looking for "practical" applications of homomorphic encryption.

A question that would be a better fit for crypto.se will still be migrated, and I personally have never seen somebody object to a migration. Afterall, the goal of a migration is to get a question where it is the most likely to be seen by someone who can answer it well.